# Don't want this to occur

Tags: modeling

Hello i'm new to blender and been following tutorials and up til now have been having fun with blender but all the sudden while following a tutorial on how to build a small temple, blender seems to be automatically joining my column to the base of the temple and when trying to hide the temple it's hiding both the column and temple. At one point it worked as expected and hid the temple but when i went to sub-divide the column it also affected my temple. What am i doing wrong?. it seems to me that if i scale the column but don't let it touch any other part of the model it works as expected but if i scale the column so it touches the ceiling and floor before hiding i can't work on any one thing because now they are both one object...Please Help!!.

Comment: NM been up a long the, problem was i forgot to switch to object mode before  adding new object lol..

Comment: Please use meaningful headlines and also try to use basic formatting. Please have a [read](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/could-we-brush-up-the-help-center-please)

Comment: Most of us would have fallen for that one Mingo!  lol